# which formatter to use based on type or action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My web api uses content negotiation and there is a custom formatter that I use to render Json. However, in a small number of actions, I'd like to use the generic json formatter that comes with asp.net.

In the configureServices, I add my formatter and then the JsonOutputFormatter.

How do I set which actions or types use which serializer? Or is there a way to disallow the generic formatter to serve some types or actions?

The types that were supposed to be formatted with my custom formatter, in some settings, are formatted using the standard json formatter. And this change from setting to setting.
For example,  when deployed to azure and called from a code running in the browser, using the accept header `"application/json, text/plain, */*"`, it uses the standard Json formatter where as the same code when run in kestrel in my computer uses my custom json formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In formatter constructor you may declare valid media types / encodings.

   ```
   public YourOutputFormatter()
   {
       SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("<media types>"));

       SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
   }
   ```
2. You may override `CanWriteType` or `CanWriteResult` methods in your formatter. As `CanWriteType` method checks only if you can serialize from the type

   ```
   protected virtual bool CanWriteType(Type type);
   ```

   the `CanWriteResult` should be more appropriate for you case:

   ```
   public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
   {
      // return true/false based on context.ContentType
      // there is also context.ObjectType
   }
   ```

   From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-formatters):

   > Use `CanWriteResult` if the following conditions are true:
   >
   > - Your action method returns a model class.
   > - There are derived classes which might be returned at runtime.
   > - You need to know at runtime which derived class was returned by the action.

Comment: I already have this in my formatter. The problem is limiting the generic json formatter which is being used instead of the custom one.

Comment: @cellik and you can use your own formatter, inherited from JsonOutputFormatter, instead of the generic json formatter and override it's behavior as well